# how to solve the following error while creating new laravel project

Tags: laravel, homestead

i am new to homestead and laravel , i am trying to install homestead and start new laravel proeject , i follow the steps in the following link , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il08--droNI, it seems that i succeed to install homestead then i started
vargant up 
and installed the laravel inside my Homestead folder using the following command 
composer global require laravel/installer 
now i am trying to start the new project using the following command 
laravel new blog 
but it gives me the following errors

```
Crafting application...
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/code/laravel_816486aaffc1239c550dccbdbf28f281.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 147

Warning: file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/code/laravel_816486aaffc1239c550dccbdbf28f281.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 147
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 169

Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 169
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 171

Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 171
You should verify that the "storage" and "bootstrap/cache" directories are writable.

In Process.php line 332:

  The provided cwd "/home/vagrant/code/myproject" does not exist.


new [--dev] [--auth] [-f|--force] [--] [<name>]

vagrant@homestead:~/code$ ^C
```

here is my .yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox



folders:
    - map: C:\Users\hit-ham\laravel-apps
      to: /home/vagrant/code
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: myproject.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/myproject/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

my Homestead folder is in users/myname

edit: i tried to remove everything and setup new windows , and start everything from the begining , installing vagrant , virtual box , composer, but i have now new error

```
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for league/flysystem 1.0.67 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.67].
    - league/flysystem 1.0.67 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - league/flysystem 1.0.67 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.6.2 requires league/flysystem ^1.0.8 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.67].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v7.6.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.6.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php7\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: It looks like it's saying you don't have permission to write to that folder(s). What I've done in the past to create a new project is do it from within my VH. What happens if you `cd` into your `Homestead` directory and do `vagrant ssh`? If you can get logged in, do an `ls` to see what folders are there. If you can find `/home/vagrant/code` cd into that. Once in there, _THEN_ try `laravel new blog`.

Answer (score 1):

or in windows with IIS

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

In the php.ini file, uncomment the following line `extension = fileinfo`